# JavaScript - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can't find the problem, but it keeps showing this error!! same happens when using other methods like includes.

```js
let notes = [{},{
    title: 'My next trip',
    body: 'I would like to go to Spain'
},{
    title: 'Habits to work on',
    body: 'Exercise. Eating a bit better'
},{
    title: 'Office modification',
    body: 'Get a new seat'
}]

let filteredNotes = notes.filter( function (note, index) {
    let findFileredTitle = note.title.toLowerCase().includes('ne')
    let findFileredBody = note.body.toLowerCase().includes('ne')

    return findFileredTitle || findFileredBody
})
console.log(filteredNotes)
```

Comment: Please do not use pictures of code, it can easily be copy and pasted into the question itself and formatted. It is much easier for users to work with than an image.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array *notes* contains four elements. The first one empty. See the empty pair of braces?

```
let notes = [{}, {
```

When you later access it:

```
note.title.toLowerCase() === ...
```

Then *note.title* is undefined and you get the error message.

Most likely, you want to remote the empty pair of braces.

Answer (score 1):

There is an object with no property `title`, because of that you're getting that error.  It's something like:

```
undefined.toLowercase()
        ^
```

You can add a checking part on `note.title` as follow:

```
note.title && (note.title.toLowercase() === .........)
     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your filter method to check if key exists then going for match other return `false`.

```
let filteredNotes = notes.filter( function (note, index) {
    let findFileredTitle = note.title && note.title.toLowerCase().includes('ne')
    let findFileredBody = note.body && note.body.toLowerCase().includes('ne')

    return findFileredTitle || findFileredBody
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issue** : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: field.label is undefined

**Solution**

```
field.label && field.label.toLowerCase()
```

**Note**

- First check field.label before accessing toLowerCase property

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide null check before converting tilte and body to lowercase.

```js
let notes = [{},{
    title: 'My next trip',
    body: 'I would like to go to Spain'
},{
    title: 'Habits to work on',
    body: 'Exercise. Eating a bit better'
},{
    title: 'Office modification',
    body: 'Get a new seat'
}]

let filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note, index) {
  let findFileredTitle = '';
    if(note.title){
      findFileredTitle = note.title.toLowerCase().includes('ne')
    }
    let findFileredBody = '';
    if(note.body){
      findFileredBody = note.body.toLowerCase().includes('ne');
    }

    return findFileredTitle || findFileredBody
})
console.log(filteredNotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove An empty '{}' object from array , note.title is null/Empty so it return error

```
let notes = [{
    title: 'My next trip',
    body: 'I would like to go to Spain'
},{
    title: 'Habits to work on',
    body: 'Exercise. Eating a bit better'
},{
    title: 'Office modification',
    body: 'Get a new seat'
}]
```